# What does it mean to say that an interface is also a type?

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I think that it means that via the concept of polymorphism, a variable's type can be declared to be that of an interface. For ex: if Animal is an interface, you could code the following:

```
Animal simba = new Lion();
```

Am I correct in my understanding of this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, correct, assuming that the `Lion` class implements the `Animal` interface.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for here.  The answer currently is "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object has a **type** (and a value).* There are many types: primitive types (like `int`), class types (like `string`), enums, arrays (and perhaps I'm forgetting some).

The term "interface" refers to a particular sort of class type: it is a class which has no member objects (safe constants) and only public methods, all of which are *abstract*.**

So: an interface is a special sort of class, which in turn is a special sort of type. So interfaces *are* types. In your example, both `Animal` and `Lion` are types, and one happens to be convertible to the other.

<sub>*) Loosely, the type says "what is the structure of this", and the value says "what is the content of this". The type of `5` is `int`, and its value is... well, 5.</sub>

<sub>**) This enables you to inherit from multiple *interfaces*, while it is not possible in Java to inherit from multiple general classes.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

An `interface` can act similarly to a `superclass` in Java, in that it can take on the type of its implementations.

In your example, specifically, you define `Animal` as an `interface` which `Lion` implements.

Because of this, you can create an `Animal` of type `Lion`. The code would look like this:

```
interface Animal {
  //do interfacing stuff
}

class Lion implements Animal {
  public Lion() {
    //...
  }
  //do implementing stuff
}

class Driver {
  Animal simba = new Lion(); // This works because of polymorphism.
}
```

You are correct, though, in saying that this is an example of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).